# LocalStorage vs Сессии PHP vs БД + cookie для сравнения товаров

Tags: php, jquery, база-данных, cookie, localstorage

Есть сайт довольно крупный посещаемость +- 30k в сутки. Нужно реализовать сравнение товаров, собственно вопрос что для этого лучше использовать LocalStorage vs Сессии PHP vs БД + cookie. Пользователь в каталоге выбирает товары для сравнения жмет кнопку добавить в сравнение, потом может перейти на страницу где и будет происходить сравнение max 4-х товаров из каждой категории, т.е. пользователь может в каждой категории выбрать максимум 4 товара.

1 LocalStorage - вроде со всех сторон хорошо для данного дела, но есть пару НО ... раз данные хранятся на клиенте, то и все манипуляции придется производить на клиенте, т.е. задержки при открытии станицы + не понятно как хранить данные что бы разбивать по разделам

2 Сессии PHP - все данные хранятся на сервере и манипулировать ими намного проще, НО сессии хранятся в файлах поэтому требуют больше времени на чтение

3 БД + cookie тут и данные на сервере и читать вроде как быстро, но не совсем понятно как это скажется на нагрузке при большой посещаемости

Посоветуйте как бы вы сделали? как оптимальние? важна скорость загрузки страницы

Comment: какие-то невнятные придуманные проблемы и неясные пути реализации. Вы решите организационные вопросы - нужно ли чтобы клиент заходя с другого устройства видел своим списки сравнений или нет. Если нужно, то очевидно хранить данные надо на сервере. Клиент ваш вообще авторизуется? тогда сессия у вас уже используется. Медленные сесссии в файлах, удивительно, но их можно хранить где угодно, кроме файлов, хоть БД хоть другие средства кэширования. БД+куки вообще не ясно что-такое.

Comment: при любом "выборе" вы все равно будете запрашивать данные в БД.

Comment: @teran это вроде и не проблемы, просто мысли в слух) Нет посетители не авторизованы. По поводу нужно ли что бы пользователь мог видеть списки сравнения с любого устройства, скорее не важно. БД + куки имелось ввиду что создавать уникальную куку и записывать в бд эту куку + id товаров, потом проверять эту куку у пользователя если есть искать запись в бд с id товаров по этой куке, но вот пока писал понял что лучше писать это не в бд, а например в redis